# Weird behavior with tag syntax on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

There's some squirrely behavior going on when using the `[tag:tag]` syntax for linking tags on Meta.

In Chrome (29.0.1547.76 m, Windows 7), when written in one continuous line in Markdown, tags overflow both the preview pane of the editor and the page:

[image: editor]
[image: actually a question]

The same happens in Firefox (24.0, Windows 7):

[image: question.firefox]

In IE 10 (10.0.8), the tags *do* wrap. However, it cuts a tag on the boundary into two pieces:

[image: question.IE]

[Here](https://meta.superuser.com/revisions/7232/1) is a post that produces this behavior.

Comment: Added spaces as a workaround so the linked question doesn't break.

Comment: Screenshots of this site, posted in a question on this site are always extremely confusing. :P

Comment: Finding oddities of behavior in MS browsers is sadly not uncommon.  MS plays very fast (in a bad way) and loose (also in a bad way) with things that should be standards.  Noticing that MS has screwed it up shouldn't be surprising in any way, shape, or form.  Making it the responsibility of the site to fix seems ... irresponsible at best.  Mayhap you should be complaining to those responsible for the IE bad decisions so they get their butts on-board with legitimate standards.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed and will be deployed in the next build.