# Bottom border of tags is cut off when editing or creating posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, css

I first noticed this in the review queue on the main site, but it also occurs on both the main site and the meta site when asking a question.

#### Main site, review queue

[image: main site, review queue]

#### Meta site, asking a new question

[image: meta site]

Is this a bug, or something peculiar to my setup? Can anyone reproduce this? It appears in both Iceweasel 17.0.8 and Chromium 29.0.1547.57, the only browsers I have access to at the moment, on my x64 Debian system. The old version of Iceweasel may not be a [supported browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/218097), but I believe this version of Chromium is supported.

My browsers are using all the default settings (zoom, etc.), as far as I know. I didn't notice this on the few other sites I checked, e.g. webapps.SE, SO, money.SE, etc. (sites where I'm active, basically).

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior with Chrome and Firefox on Windows 7 (x64).

Comment: [If I had to guess…](http://meta.superuser.com/a/7246)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.

Fixed!

Comment: May I ask if tags displayed in two lines are a new behavior or an old/intentional? http://i.stack.imgur.com/sBEQz.png (Windows 7 x64, Opera 12 | Chrome 30 | Firefox 25)

Comment: It is new and intentional, @nixda

Comment: Thx. I like the new style because it fixed a display bug in Opera where you got vertical scroll bars in the case mentioned above :)